# .htaccess https rewrite for single domain on multisite installation

Tags: 7, multi-sites, .htaccess, ssl

I have a multisite installation with 2 sites running off separate domains. One of these sites needs to go through https:// while the the other can stick to http://. I also want all traffic to be rewritten to include the www. prefix.

So:

**example.com** rewritten to **https://www.example.com**

**example.co.uk** rewritten to **http://www.example.co.uk**

I'm trying to set my `.htaccess` file to handle this, and have tried with the  syntax discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776690/htaccess-redirect-if-domain-is-not-correct).

```
RewriteEngine on
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'">
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</If>
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.co.uk'">
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !http
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</If>
```

Needless to say, it's not working. Any input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First I would try using the [drupal]/sites/sites.php file to do something like this:

```
$sites['example.co.uk'] = 'example.com';
$sites['example.com'] = 'example.com'; // for demonstration only
```

Then check out the [htaccess module](https://www.drupal.org/project/htaccess) to force HTTPS. These are the  options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but would the following work:

```
# Force HTTPS for example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

# Force HTTP for example.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately that's not working either. Looking at it with an htaccess tester it is rewriting the URL to https://www.example.com/example.com 

I've tried a few more things and have a version that works on the htaccess tester, but returns an infinite loop once it's up on the server and I try it there:

Comment: #.com to https://www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    
#.co.uk to http://www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Think your loop is caused by missing the RewriteCond %{HTTPS} lines

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is don't change anything except redirect `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` with following (

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And if you like to redirect `https://example.co.uk`  to http://example.co.uk`add the following line to your`.htaccess` file ( but I don't think you need them)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Also, you can try to set them with [Htaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/htaccess) module

> Htaccess is a module which autogenerates a Drupal root htaccess file
>   based on your settings.
>
> Drupal tries to provide a one size fits all htaccess for Apache
>   webservers, but this goal is increasingly difficult. This module
>   allows the webmaster to set specific options.
>
> Also, this module is dedicated to webmasters who don't want to
>   manually modify htaccess every time during a version upgrade to use
>   Drupal.

**Features:**
 - Set redirection to www or non www.
 - Use Followsymlinks or SymlinksIfOwnersMatch.
 - HTTPS support (redirect all request to HTTPS or support both protocols).
 - Protect core text files (like CHANGELOG.txt) from being viewed.
 - Ability to insert Boost htaccess settings
 - Add custom rules before Drupal rules.
 - Each htaccess is attached to a profile. This way, you can manage several
 - htaccess files and deploy the right one to your website.
 - Check if htaccess is altered and report in site status .
 - List item
 - Drush integration.